# Phrase for correcting text in a particular manner

Tags: phrase-requests

If someone writes in a manner such as "U hve to run daily ... only then U will lose weight" and you correct it to "You have to run daily, only then you will lose weight." I suppose you can't say you have corrected grammar. What can you say you have corrected? Punctuation?

Comment: It's grammar, all right. *U* and *hve* are not 'words' in formal English writing, hence ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you've corrected their writing style. They were writing in an informal slang style. It's been corrected to a more formal style.

I suppose you *could* say you've corrected the spelling, since "U" to mean "you" may not be in most dictionaries. It depends on if you see "U" as a slang word in its own right or as a misspelling of "you".

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of spelling. In the conventional orthography of Standard English, the second person personal pronoun is spelt *you* and not *u*, and the verb is spelt *have* and not *hve*.

Answer (score 1):

You have translated text speak into English. But it is still not fully correct. 'Only then you will lose weight' should read 'Only then will you lose weight'.